# Template for variable length initializer

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I need a family of initializer functions with variable number of values used. I'm using them to implement a gather operation with Eigen library. Here is the way I'm doing it now with one template for each vector length:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline void gather (Array<T1,4,1> &to, const Array<T2,Dynamic,1> &from, const Array<int,4,1> &index) 
{
    to << from[index[0]], from[index[1]], from[index[2]], from[index[3]];
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline void gather (Array<T1,6,1> &to, const Array<T2,Dynamic,1> &from, const Array<int,6,1> &index) 
{
    to << from[index[0]], from[index[1]], from[index[2]], from[index[3]], from[index[4]], from[index[5]];
}
```

Is there a way to replace a **longer list** of templates like above with a single template parametrized with length parameter (4 and 6 in snippet above)? If so, can it be done with pre C++11 language specs (I'm using Visual Studio 2010)?

I would like to retain the comma separated values syntax, as I hope it may produce a compile time initialization in some cases (const `from` and `index`). I may be wrong in this assumption though. The initializer list can have 1 to 16 values - there is no need to worry about an empty list.

Comment: I take it you're looking for a way to do this with automatic deduction, yes ? Also, is that supposed to be an insertion-chain (to << val << val << val..) or are the commas all intended?

Comment: The commas are needed - such is a syntax of Eigen initializer. I hope it produces compile time initialization.

Comment: There is possible way this does any initialization at compile-time, since you're dealing with already initialized data.

Comment: @Xeo Did you mean "There is no possible way"?

Comment: @Paul: Err... yes. :( Damn typos changing the whole meaning. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the comma initializer syntax in this setting, it's going to be cumbersome. This syntax is used for readability when using literals, which is not your case.

Instead, I would recommend something like:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, unsigned int SIZE, unsigned int INDEX>
struct gather {
   gather(Array<T1,SIZE,1> &to, 
          const Array<T2,Dynamic,1> &from, 
          const Array<int,SIZE,1> &index) 
   {
      to.col(INDEX) = from[index[INDEX]];
      gather<T1,T2,SIZE,INDEX+1>(to,from, index);
   }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, unsigned int SIZE>
struct gather<T1,T2,SIZE,SIZE>{
    gather(Array<T1,SIZE,1> &to, 
           const Array<T2,Dynamic,1> &from, 
           const Array<int,SIZE,1> &index)
    {
    }
};
```

which nicely produces the same effect, but statically (no loop).

I am using a struct here because of the partial template specialization restriction on functions, but it should come down to the same, because of inlining.

Comment: It seems that `CommaInitializer` can't perform compile time initialization, so this solution or even the loop solution (answer was deleted) will do.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite tricky to generalize this syntax based on overloading the `operator,` operator, and the result looks awkward at best (if it works). I would recommend trying other options (eg. go for the [`MatrixBase::operator<<(DenseBase&)`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a3dacded5374fe30f8d4eb4ae18bc87c9) operator).

If you want it still, you must unpack the scalars one-by-one:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, class CI, int Current, int Height>
inline void gather (Array<T1,Height,1> &to, const Array<T2,Dynamic,1> &from, const Array<int,Height,1> &index, CI&& ci, std::integral_constant<int, Current>*)
{
  gather(to, from, index, (ci,from[index[Current]]), (std::integral_constant<int, Current+1>*)0);
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, class CI, int Height>
inline void gather (Array<T1,Height,1> &to, const Array<T2,Dynamic,1> &from, const Array<int,Height,1> &index, CI&& ci, std::integral_constant<int, Height>*) {}

template<typename T1, typename T2, int Height>
inline void gather (Array<T1,Height,1> &to, const Array<T2,Dynamic,1> &from, const Array<int,Height,1> &index) {
  gather(to, from, index, (to << index[from[0]]), (std::integral_constant<int, 1>*)0);
}
```

Ugly, and there may be problems (you need to handle the `Dynamic` value, zero height if that's possible, there may be problems passing `CommaInitializers` to the recursion etc.)

Plus, it has linear template instantiation depth (and IMHO that's unavoidable in this case).

Comment: @jplacek Zero elements is not an issue - I edited my question. I agree, it is ugly :-) On top of that, I have only a faint clue about what it actually does.